# Changing field separator

Tags: mysql

I can see that using maatkit I can export the data as comma or tab separated values. But is there anyway to change the field separator?

http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-dump.html

I have a table that has comma as well as tabs in the data. Besides I need to process the data using awk that does not seem to work with certain fields data. I want to change the separator while dumping data using maatkit. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commas present in data should not cause any problem:  the text fields (and maybe all fields) are within quotes:

```
"field 1 value", "field 2 value", 3.38823, "field 4 value"
```

Comment: When I use awk with field separator as comma, it is confused if the data has a comma too.